# How Can I Correctly Attach new 4x4 Deck Rail Posts on the surface to an existing deck?

Tags: deck, railing

The previous 4x4 deck rail posts were notched and attached with nails on the outside of the deck.  We have replaced many deck boards (2x6 pt) and want to replace the railing using 4x4 rail posts.  We are unable to bolt them on the outside or on the surface in all of the proper places due to the location and layout of the deck and would like to mount them on the surface.

Is there a proper surface mounted bracket to do this that would be to code? or close to code? Some of the deck is above 8' off the ground.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of options, but none are pretty. Also, you may need to add sub-decking framing members to support such brackets.

To steer clear of (off-topic) product recommendations, I'll instead suggest this: Mount your posts to the inside of your rim joists, through the decking. You'll get a more solid railing and it'll look better. It'll look something like this (you'll probably need to use lag bolts from the inside of the posts, into the joists):

[image]

[image]